# Spring boot 3 missing jvm metrics common tags

Tags: spring-boot

After spring boot 2 to 3 migration i noticed that service disappeared from grafana dashboard. After a short investigation turned out that common tags are not applied to jvm metrics in spring boot 3.
In spring boot 2 application.yaml was like this

```
management:
  metrics:
    tags:
      application: demo2
```

and produced prometheus metrics like this

```
# HELP jvm_memory_used_bytes The amount of used memory
# TYPE jvm_memory_used_bytes gauge
jvm_memory_used_bytes{application="demo2",area="nonheap",id="Compressed Class Space",} 4668760.0
jvm_memory_used_bytes{application="demo2",area="heap",id="G1 Eden Space",} 0.0
jvm_memory_used_bytes{application="demo2",area="heap",id="G1 Old Gen",} 1.4173592E7
jvm_memory_used_bytes{application="demo2",area="nonheap",id="Metaspace",} 3.400088E7
jvm_memory_used_bytes{application="demo2",area="heap",id="G1 Survivor Space",} 4822464.0
jvm_memory_used_bytes{application="demo2",area="nonheap",id="CodeCache",} 8376192.0
```

In spring boot 3 application.yaml was migrated like this

```
management:
  observations:
    key-values:
      application: demo3
```

and produced prometheus metrics were these (without "application" tag)

```
# HELP jvm_memory_used_bytes The amount of used memory
# TYPE jvm_memory_used_bytes gauge
jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Survivor Space",} 3707904.0
jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Old Gen",} 1.48822E7
jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Metaspace",} 3.4899392E7
jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeCache",} 8664704.0
jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Eden Space",} 2.5165824E7
jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Compressed Class Space",} 4869608.0
```

Any ideas what have I overlooked while migration?

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is an issue on Spring for this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38583

Replicated here: https://github.com/sbernardo/spring-issues-examples with spring-boot 3.2.0 and java 21.

NOTE: using deprecated key `management.metrics.tags.application=${spring.application.name}` tag "application" appears

**UPDATE:**

Spring updated the issue and closed it with this comment:

> We decided to undeprecate `management.metrics.tags` for now, and we'll rethink about the whole tags (and key-values) situation in a next release.

In Spring-Boot 3.2.1 maybe old behavior will be restored.